# Enable CORS in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cross-domain, cors

I'm trying to enable CORS in WordPress and I've placed this line of code in my `header.php` file

`header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Then I tested to see if it works via this page http://client.cors-api.appspot.com/client

The response I get is:

```
Fired XHR event: loadstart
Fired XHR event: readystatechange
Fired XHR event: error

XHR status: 0
XHR status text: 
Fired XHR event: loadend
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, anybody able to help me out?

Comment: You can view the request in Chrome's Network tab. This will show you whether the response has the correct header or not.

Comment: I would put the header() call in your wp-config.php I'm pretty sure  when header.php is called headers have already been sent.

Comment: Alternatively, you can configure your server to send the header: http://enable-cors.org/server.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable CORS on a Wordpress Subdomain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38378729/how-to-enable-cors-on-a-wordpress-subdomain)

Answer (score -1):

You can also enable CORS directly in Apache by including the line:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Include this line within the `<Directory>`, `<Location>`, `<Files>` or `<VirtualHost>` sections of your server config (usually located in a *.conf file, such as httpd.conf or apache.conf), or within a .htaccess file.

Additional information, including how to check for errors and/or reboot apache at https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html